# How to get the modified data from swagger editor in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, swagger, swagger-editor

I am using swagger version 3 and with angular js. I have integrated swagger editor with angular js. Now i am stuck in getting the data that is displayed in the swagger editor and then pass to the server. below is my code:-
Html code:-

```
<div id="swagger-editor-container" class="swagger-ui-wrap" ng-model="textVal">
```

controller:-

```
$scope.submit = function(obj){
    console.log("value of textarea");
    console.log(obj);
    console.log($scope.textVal);
    $scope.status = "Updating";
    $scope.renderJson = false;

    UploadFileService.uploadToS3(angular.toJson(obj))
        .then(function(res){

        console.log(res);
        getData();

    },
function(err){
    console.log(err);
})
```

}

I cant able to get the data from swagger editor it is showing "undefined" in the console.log. Any way to get the data from swagger editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can retrieve data from local storage, swagger editor is storing in the localstorage. so you can get the data by using following code in angular js:-

```
let swaggerEditorData = window.localStorage.getItem('swagger-editor-content');
```

2.) Alternative way is using the inbuilt function:-

```
ui.specSelectors.specStr();
```